# Union of types in flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

I'm trying to define a union of types in flutter as type of a variable. I would like to achieve something like this:

```
class Type1 {
  String attr1;
  Map<String, String> attr2;
  Type1();
}

class Type2 {
  String attr1;
  String attr2;
  Type2();
}

Union2<Type1, Type2> myInstance;
```

Or

```
Union2<String, int> stringOrInt;
```

I don't want to use `dynamic`.

I found an old package called [union](https://pub.dev/packages/union), however it is discontinued. Do you know another way to proceed for my purpose ?

Thanks a lot for your answer !

PS: for information, I need the Union type to create my Hive dataset adapters (boxes may have different object values).

Comment: Do you really need a package for that? Can't you just define a third class like `class Pair<T, D>` with a field of type T and one of type D?

Comment: I have almost 12 different subtypes possible for my ScreenData object. Thus, I think that using a class Pair<T, D, ...> wouldn't be very clean...

Comment: Well, you could create an abstract class that T and/or D would extend, so it would be less "random" than a generic `Object`. Something like `Pair<T extends AbstractOne, D extends AbstractTwo>`, but it's up to you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use [freezed](https://pub.dev/packages/freezed) which is code generator for data-classes/unions/pattern-matching/cloning.

This is how we write union with freezed.

```dart
@freezed
class Union with _$Union {
  const factory Union.data(int value) = Data;
  const factory Union.loading() = Loading;
  const factory Union.error([String? message]) = Error;
}
```

Start using freezed and you won't regret it. It is awesome package to have.

And the types are, `Data`, `Loading` and `Error`.

```dart
var union = Union(42);
if(union is Data) {
  print(union.value);
}
```

Or with pattern matching,

```dart
var union = Union(42);

print(
  union.when(
    (int value) => 'Data $value',
    loading: () => 'loading',
    error: (String? message) => 'Error: $message',
  ),
);
```

Comment: I can only agree, freezed is awesome 

Comment: Thanks a lot for your response, I tried out this package and it is really nice ! Exactly what I needed :)

Answer (score 1):

you can use [sealed](https://dart.dev/language/class-modifiers#sealed) classes that introduced in dart3 or you can use [Either package](https://pub.dev/packages/either_dart)

Answer (score 0):

in Dart 3 and later you can use sealed Class,

https://dart.dev/language/class-modifiers#sealed

```dart
sealed class Vehicle {}

class Car extends Vehicle {}

class Truck implements Vehicle {}

class Bicycle extends Vehicle {}

// ERROR: Cannot be instantiated
Vehicle myVehicle = Vehicle();

// Subclasses can be instantiated
Vehicle myCar = Car();

String getVehicleSound(Vehicle vehicle) {
  // ERROR: The switch is missing the Bicycle subtype or a default case.
  return switch (vehicle) {
    Car() => 'vroom',
    Truck() => 'VROOOOMM',
  };
}
```

Answer (score -2):

Tuple is what you need:
https://pub.dev/packages/tuple

Used like this:

```
const t = Tuple2<String, int>('a', 10);
print(t.item1); // prints 'a'
print(t.item2); // prints 10
```

Comment: A Tuple is a Product type (more than one value/type). It is not a Sum (union) type where you have type one or type two.

Answer (score -6):

Union Types:

Dart supports union types, also known as "sum types" or "tagged unions". You can define a type that can hold values of different types using the | operator.

Example in Dart:

typedef MyUnion = int | String;

void main() {
MyUnion myValue = 42;    // Valid
print(myValue); // Output: 42

myValue = "hello";   // Valid
print(myValue); // Output: hello

// myValue = true;   // Invalid (since boolean is not part of the union)
}

Comment: I believe this is completely incorrect, as per my testing in Dart 3