# Union type for primitive types data in dart

Tags: typescript, flutter, dart, primitive, union-types

How can I define a variable with only two possible primitive types, such as (String or num) for example, in Dart? Is there a way to do this?
like union types in TypeScript.

```
const x:string|number;
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/73077321/9727402

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Union of types in flutter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73077321/union-of-types-in-flutter)

Comment: There is no clear explanation about the primitive types of data. They talk about objects

Comment: Because Dart doesn't have the union type like you wanted. So the answers from that question are literally the solution.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer. The answer I want is "there is no union in dart yet". The sealed class does not achieve what I want. I asked to make sure that there is no modern way to do this using generics and extensions and the latest Dart updates.

Comment: I need this feature because using dynamic type is annoying in some cases and inconvenient. Why should I declare a variable that should only have two primitive types as dynamic and accept any value!

Answer (score 1):

**Related Info/Resources:**

This question is a possible duplicate of this question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73077321/union-of-types-in-flutter#:%7E:text=Dart%20supports%20union%20types%2C%20also,different%20types%20using%20the%20%7C%20operator.).

There WAS a [union](https://pub.dev/packages/union) package that has been discontinued. It was replaced by the [freezed](https://pub.dev/packages/freezed) package, which includes the functionality you are looking for but with a bunch of other stuff as well.

I think you may be interested in dart's [sealed](https://dart.dev/language/class-modifiers#sealed) classes or the [either](https://pub.dev/packages/either_dart) package.

**Ideas for implementing from scratch:**

To achieve the functionality you are looking for, you could create your own class that takes a dynamic type in its constructor, and throws an error if the type does not evaluate to one of the types that you want to enforce.

Comment: sealed class for primitive types ?.. how ?

Comment: for primitive types not for objects

Answer (score 1):

I'll add another recommendation for [Freezed](https://pub.dev/packages/freezed). It's a good package that will solve your problem and can also be used for things like data classes w/ JSON support.

If you don't want to add dependencies / use code generation / whatever, you can write your own sealed class:

```dart
sealed class MyUnion {
  const MyUnion();

  static MyUnion fromResponse(Object response) {
    return switch (response) {
      int val => MyInt(val),
      String val => MyString(val),
      _ => throw UnimplementedError('Unsupported type ${response.runtimeType}'),
    };
  }
}

class MyInt extends MyUnion {
  const MyInt(this.val);
  final int val;
}

class MyString extends MyUnion {
  const MyString(this.val);
  final String val;
}

void main() {
  printUnion(const MyInt(1));
  printUnion(const MyString('Hello World'));
  printUnion(MyUnion.fromResponse(10));
  printUnion(MyUnion.fromResponse('ten'));
}

void printUnion(MyUnion arg) {
  switch (arg) {
    case MyInt(:final val):
      print('Found int: $val');
    case MyString(:final val):
      print('Found String: $val');
  }
}
```

As an aside: Dart does not have primitive types. It has built in types, but every type except `Null` is a subtype of `Object`.

Comment: In this way, I am forced to assign one of the two values to the variable. For example, if the variable comes from the API, I do not know its type. How will I know it to be one of the two values num or String, and if it is not, throw an Exception? I need a type that combines the two types like TypeScript.

Comment: For example, if I have a value "value" that can be either a String or a num, how do I create a variable x that accepts both types?

Type x = value as string; // Correct

Also:

Type x = value as double; // Correct

If there was a way using extensions and generics to create a type that combines the two, it would be great.

Comment: Dart doesn't have union types like that. If you don't want to do additional processing on the API response, the best you'll have is `Object` (or `Object?`). If you want something more strongly typed then you'll need a deserialization step to check the types and perform the conversion. I updated my example code to include a simple implementation in the sealed class. If you're using json_serializable it's possible to define custom logic for deserializing different types.